# How to apply multiple css3 rotations on a single element with transition

Tags: html, css

I want to implement something like this:

```
img{
    transition: 5s linear;
    transform: scale(2,2) rotate(-20deg) rotate(40deg) rotate(-40deg) rotate(20deg) scale(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

But is just scales a bit and then scales back to the original size.

Comment: All rotations add up to 0. So obviously you only see a scaled up thing for some time and then a scaled down thing.

Comment: Also, what do you really wanna do? Visual examples? What do you mean by multiple rotations?

Comment: I think you need an animation rather than transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to create an element and add to it animation using keyframes, as in the example below:

```css
.element {
  animation: rotate 5s infinite;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
  }
  25% {
     transform: rotate(20deg); 
  }
  50% {
     transform: rotate(-20deg); 
  }
  75% {
     transform: rotate(20deg); 
  }
  100% {
     transform: rotate(-20deg); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="element"> </div>
```

You can find more information about it here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use animation over transition.

```
@keyframes{
  0%{
      //your transform
  }
  50%{
      //your transform
  }
  100%{
      //your transform
  }
}
```